# Find and report all line numbers at which the longest word in a file appears using an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

This program provides takes in command line args which are names of text files, and returns basic statistics like the number of characters, words, and lines, the average word length, and the number of each letter and word length.

**I have everything working except this:** Find and report all line numbers at which the longest word in a file appears using an ArrayList to track line numbers, since we don't know how many occurrences of the longest word there are. If there are two or more different words of the same longest length, then track the first one only. **How do I do this?**

```js
  try {
    fileName = file.getName();
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);

    while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) { // Scan each line of the file
      lineNumber++;

      String line = fileScan.nextLine();

      // Count the number of occurrences of each alphabet(convert all to lower-case)
      for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        current = line.toLowerCase().charAt(i);

        if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z') {
          letterCount[current - 'a'] ++; // 
        }

      }
      charCount += line.length();

      Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
      lineScan.useDelimiter(DELIMITERS);
      while (lineScan.hasNext()) { // Scan each line into words using custom delimiters
        word = lineScan.next();
        wordCount++;

        // Find the no. of words of each length
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH; i++) {
          if (word.length() == i) {
            wordLengthCount[i] ++;
          }
        }

      }


      lineScan.close();
    }

    // Find the average word length 
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH; i++) {
      totalWordLength += (i * wordLengthCount[i]);
    }
    averageWordLength = (double) totalWordLength / wordCount;

    fileScan.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid file path: " + file.getName());
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: **How do I do this -** find and report all line numbers at which the longest word in a file appears using an ArrayList to track line numbers, since we don't know how many occurrences of the longest word there are. If there are two or more different words of the same longest length, then track the first one only.

Comment: Well, You can see a file content as a list of lines. And you can view a line as a list of words. When reading the file, you can construct this list. Since you can already find the longest word, you then need to loop through your lines to find the ones which contain the longest word.

Comment: Dude, I get the logic behind it, I wrote the rest of the program after all. I'm having trouble with writing the actual code, how I would use an ArrayList and how I would account for duplicate occurrences of the word.

Comment: To do that, you would look at the documentation for ArrayList. You would google for "Java collections tutorial" to understand how they work, what their characteristics are, etc. And you would try something. That's what all developers in the world do every day: use classes and APIs that they never used before, by reading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As this is homework, just a *partial* solution to look at some approaches and posible API usage:

Here the approach for the lines is to hold the longest word upto the currently processed lines. If a longer word is found, clear the list.

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/home/...");

    int longestWordLength = 0;
    List<Integer> linesWithLongestWord = new ArrayList<>();

    int lineno = 0;
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : lines) {
        ++lineno; // 1-based line numbers
        String[] words = line.split("\\P{L}+");
        int longest = Stream.of(words)
                .mapToInt(String::length)
                .max().orElse(0);
        if (longest > longestWordLength) {
            linesWithLongestWord.clear();
            longestWordLength = longest;             
            linesWithLongestWord.add(lineno);
        } else if (longest == longestWordLength) {
            linesWithLongestWord.add(lineno);
        }
    }        
    System.out.printf("Max %d, %s%n", longestWordLength, linesWithLongestWord);
```

Words are derived by using `String.split(regular_expression)` where `\P{L}` are the non-letters (capital P = non).

I threw in a java 8 stream on the words to fetch the maximal length, for its ease. You probably want the maximal word in a local variable outside the loop. Here "longest word" is reduced to a length.

After the loop one can tell what really is the maximal word and such.